# How to write QuerySet for Django to get models count

Tags: django, django-views

Model.py

class InventoryData(models.Model):

```
AssetID = models.CharField('Asset ID', max_length=30, unique=True)
SerialNumber = models.CharField('Serial Number', max_length=30, unique=True)
Make = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
Model = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Inventory Data'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Inventory Data'

def __str__(self):
    return self.AssetID
```

Views.py

def home(request):

```
obj = InventoryData
# ----- For Models ----- #
stnd = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='laptop').order_by('Model').values_list('Model', 
flat=True).distinct()
dev = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='developer').order_by('Model').values_list('Model', 
flat=True).distinct()
mac = obj.objects.filter(Make__startswith='Apple').order_by('Model').values_list('Model', 
flat=True).distinct()
desk = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='laptop').order_by('Model').values_list('Model', 
flat=True).distinct()

# ----- For Counts ----- #

cnt = obj.objects.filter(Model__in=mac).distinct().count()  

context = {'stnd': stnd, 'dev': dev, 'mac': mac, 'desk': desk, 'cnt': cnt, }

return render(request, 'App/home.html', context)
```

this is output i am getting:

in my DB i have Make as **Apple, Lenovo** and Model as 4 models [**MacBook Pro 13.0", MacBook Pro 15.0", T440, T450, T540p**], each model has 10 laptops, but when i count i am getting total count as **20** for Mac Book and count as **30** for Lenovo Laptops, i need count for every model as

MacBook Pro 13.0" -- 10
MacBook Pro 15.0" -- 10
T440              -- 10
T450              -- 10
T540p             -- 10

with below query i am getting below table,

cnt = obj.objects.filter(Model__in=mac).count()

please help me how to write query for table 2

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpJOc.png)

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5i54.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple group by would return your counts:

```
from django.db.models import Count

stnd = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='laptop').values('Model').annotate(count=Count('Model'))

dev = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='developer').values('Model').annotate(count=Count('Model'))

mac = obj.objects.filter(Make__startswith='Apple').values('Model').annotate(count=Count('Model'))

desk = obj.objects.filter(AssetID__startswith='laptop').values('Model').annotate(count=Count('Model'))

context = {'stnd': stnd, 'dev': dev, 'mac': mac, 'desk': desk, }


return render(request, 'App/home.html', context)

# Template

{% for key, value in mac.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

It should render something like this:

```
Model: MacBook Pro 13.0
count: 10

Model:  MacBook Pro 15.0
count: 10
```

It would much simpler if you have a better way of identifying what kind of product is that. Like for instance, if you could identify what is the maker of a product by `Make` then you could group by multiple columns:

```
obj.objects.values('Make', 'Model').values(count=Count('Model'))
```

Comment: It is called [values queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values).